# Getting an images position within a ul javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the position of an image with an a ul for example:

```
function myFunction(){
  var img = document.getElementById("myID").querySelectorAll("img");
  var x = x;
  img[x].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

The function will be ran when someone clicks the image.

I want a way to get var x = the number of the image that was clicked on.

I don't know jQuery So i'd appreciate if it was all in plane javascript thanks.

Comment: How is the function being called? That's what's important to solving this issue.

Comment: What do you mean with `the number of the image that was clicked on.` Do you want the actual position within the DOM or do you have multiple images and you just want the index of the image?

Comment: @Slence he wants the index.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The fucntion is being called with an onclick='myFunction()'  tag that is inside the image

Comment: You're almost there.  Try passing the event into the function from at the onClick.  You will have access to the element that is being clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats an x y problem. Probably:

```
//wait for all clicks
window.addEventListener("click",function(event){
//check if it has a parent with id myID
  var e=event.target;
  while(e!==document.body && e.id!="myID"){
      e=e.parent;
  }
 if(e.id=="myID"){
   //set a backgroundcolor to the clicked element. May also check if Node is IMG
    event.target.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
});
```